# Snakemake: combine inputs over one wildcard

Tags: mapping, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am wondering if you would be able to give advice about defining a Snakemake rule to combine over one, but not all wildcards? My data is organized so that I have runs and samples; most, but not all samples, were resequenced in every run. Therefore, I have pre-processing steps that are per-sample-run. Then, I have a step that combines BAM files for each run per-sample. However, the issue I'm running into is that I'm a bit confused how to define a rule so that I can list an input of all indivudal bams (from different runs) corresponding to a sample.

I'm putting my entire pipeline below, for clarity, but my real question is on rule combine_bams. How can I list all bams for a single sample in the input?

Any suggestions would be great! Thank you very much in advance!

```
# Define samples and runs
RUNS, SAMPLES = glob_wildcards("/labs/jandr/walter/tb/data/Stanford/{run}/{samp}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz")
print("runs are: ", RUNS)
print("samples are: ", SAMPLES)

rule all:
  input:
     #trim = ['process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz'.format(samp=sample_id, run=run_id) for sample_id, run_id in zip(sample_ids, run_ids)],
     trim = expand(['process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz'], zip, run = RUNS, samp = SAMPLES),
     kraken=expand('process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz', zip, run = RUNS, samp = SAMPLES),
     bams=expand('process/bams/{run}_{samp}_bwa_MTB_ancestor_reference_rg_sorted.bam', zip, run = RUNS, samp = SAMPLES), # add fixed ref/mapper (expand with zip doesn't allow these to repeate)
     combined_bams=expand('process/bams/{samp}_bwa_MTB_ancestor_reference.merged.rmdup.bam', samp = np.unique(SAMPLES))

# Trim reads for quality. 
rule trim_reads:  
  input: 
    p1='/labs/jandr/walter/tb/data/Stanford/{run}/{samp}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz', # update inputs so they only include those that exist use zip.
    p2='/labs/jandr/walter/tb/data/Stanford/{run}/{samp}_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
  output: 
    trim1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz',
    trim2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_2.fq.gz'
  log: 
    'process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_reads.log'
  shell:
    '/labs/jandr/walter/tb/scripts/trim_reads.sh {input.p1} {input.p2} {output.trim1} {output.trim2} &>> {log}'

# Filter reads taxonomically with Kraken.   
rule taxonomic_filter:
  input:
    trim1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz',
    trim2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_2.fq.gz'
  output: 
    kr1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz',
    kr2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_2.fq.gz',
    kraken_stats='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_kraken.report'
  log: 
    'process/trim/{run}_{samp}_run_kraken.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    '/labs/jandr/walter/tb/scripts/run_kraken.sh {input.trim1} {input.trim2} {output.kr1} {output.kr2} {output.kraken_stats} &>> {log}'

# Map reads.
rule map_reads:
  input:
    ref_path='/labs/jandr/walter/tb/data/refs/{ref}.fasta.gz',
    kr1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz',
    kr2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_2.fq.gz'
  output:
    bam='process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_rg_sorted.bam'
  params:
    mapper='{mapper}'
  log:
    'process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_map.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    "/labs/jandr/walter/tb/scripts/map_reads.sh {input.ref_path} {params.mapper} {input.kr1} {input.kr2} {output.bam} &>> {log}"


# Combine reads and remove duplicates (per sample).
rule combine_bams:
  input:
    bams = 'process/bams/{run}_{samp}_bwa_MTB_ancestor_reference_rg_sorted.bam'
  output: 
    combined_bam = 'process/bams/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}.merged.rmdup.bam'
  log: 
     'process/bams/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_merge_bams.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    "sambamba markdup -r -p -t {threads} {input.bams} {output.combined_bam}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary to associate each sample with its list of runs.

Then for the combine_bams rule, use an input function to generate the input files for that sample using the dictionary.

```
rule combine_bams:
  input:
    bams = lambda wildcards: expand('process/bams/{run}_{{samp}}_bwa_MTB_ancestor_reference_rg_sorted.bam', run=sample_dict[wildcards.sample])
  output: 
    combined_bam = 'process/bams/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}.merged.rmdup.bam'
  log: 
     'process/bams/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_merge_bams.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    "sambamba markdup -r -p -t {threads} {input.bams} {output.combined_bam}"
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is so great and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. Best,